# Dynamic PHP Methods

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I am working on a custom DB Table Mapper in PHP.
Is it possible in PHP to make something like "virtual methods" to access the properties? Like Methods, that don't really exist.

For Example: A class "user" has the property "$name", i don't want to create a "Get" Method for this one, but i want to access the property via a virtual Method, like this: $user->GetName();

I was thinking of working with Conventions. So everytime a "virtual" Method has been called, you catch it, and check if it has the prefix "Get" or "Set".

If it has the prefix "Get" you strip the part after "Get" and make it lowercase, so you have the property you want to access.

My Idea (Pseudo Code):

```
public function VirtualMethodCalled($method_name)
{
   //Get the First 3 Chars to check if Get or Set
   $check = substr($method_name, 0, 3);

   //Get Everything after the first 3 chars to get the propertyname
   $property_name = substr($method_name, 3, 0);

   if($check=="Get")
   {
       return $this->{$property_name};
   }
   else if($check=="Set")
   {
       $this->{$property_name};
       $this->Update();
   }
   else
   {
       //throw exc
   }
}
```

Comment: PHP has some [magic methods](http://php.net/__get) you can use.

Comment: Perhaps you can look into closures. Closures, in PHP, are one-off *functions/methods* that are not actually registered into the global namespace. Throw-away functions, if you will. Typically used to extend functionality to a currently used function/method. See example #3: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a magic method to achieve this, example:

```
class A {

    private $member;


    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
      //Get the First 3 Chars to check if Get or Set
      $check = substr($method_name, 0, 3);

     //Get Everything after the first 3 chars to get the propertyname
     $property_name = substr($method_name, 3);

     if($check=="Get")
     {
       return $this->{$property_name};
     }
     else if($check=="Set")
     {
       $this->{$property_name} = $arguments[0]; //I'm assuming
     }
     else
     {
         //throw method not found exception
     }
    }
}
```

I'm mainly using the code you provided for the contents. You can obviously extend this to also handle things like function name aliases or whatever you need.

Comment: Instead of using __call magic method and having to check the first three characters of a method name your intention would be better expressed by using __set and __get. Both solutions solve the problem however the latter one is a better programming style. I've also noticed you use PascalCase convention for method/function names. That's very uncommon in the PHP world where camelCase is more popular.

Comment: @DanielStefaniuk the original question quoted dynamic setter and getter methods, there's a bigger discussion here if setters/getters are better practice than accessors/modifiers which can also be found in the Java vs C# programming conventions. I prefer implementing the __call method for these things as I generally use setters and getters for other properties as well so the overall code uses a single convention.

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry, I meant overloading __set/__get magic methods as opposed to __call which could be used for more advanced purpose.

Comment: @DanielStefaniuk yes, I also don't disagree with the PascalCase (again big debate on the C# vs Java front on this too) but again this was also in the original question. I don't think it's a big deal to use PascalCase as long as you're consistent in the rest of your code, but as you said it's not common in PHP (and in fact PSR-1 demands camelCase and not PascalCase).